# Trouble With Xen Guests on CentOS

Tags: centos, xen, xenserver

I have recently installed a new 64-bit install of CentOS 5.3 (Kernel 2.6.18-164.6.1.el5xen).  I have created a xen configuration file based on what I have done in the past on other servers.  When I do an xm create on the guest host it doesn't give any error, but when I try to connect to the host with VNC to complete my install I just get a black window, it sits there and doesn't do anything.  The mode is Blocked mode when I do an "xm list".  I am a bit confused as to what I can check next as everything I am doing as worked in the past on other xen servers.

Here is my config:

```
> [root@sheldon ~]# cat /etc/xen/staticdev1
name = "staticdev1"
vcpus= 4
memory = 512
shadow_memory = 8
builder = "hvm"
kernel = "/usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader"
boot = "dc"
#boot = "cd"
pae = 1
#acpi = 1
#apic = 1
#on_poweroff = "destroy"
#on_reboot = "restart"
#on_crash = "restart"
device_model = "/usr/lib64/xen/bin/qemu-dm"
sdl = 0
vnc = 1 
vncdisplay = 2
vncpasswd='there-is-an-actual-password-here-usually'
vnclisten='0.0.0.0'
vncunused = 1
keymap = "en-us"
disk = [ 'phy:/dev/VolGroup01/staticdev1,hda,w', 'file:/var/tmp/CentOS-5.3-x86_64-bin-DVD.iso,hdc:cdrom,r' ]
# replace above when done with ISO
#disk = [ 'phy:/dev/VolGroup01/staticdev1,hda,w' ]
#, 'phy:/dev/hdb,hdc:cdrom,r' ]
vif = [ 'mac=00:16:3e:a9:b9:ee,bridge=xenbr1' ]
#ip = '192.168.1.226'
#netmask = '255.255.255.0'
#gateway = '192.168.1.225'
serial = "pty"
stdvga=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only substantive difference I see between your config files and mine are that I've got `vncunused = 0`.  I don't know why they've got that double negative in there, but it might be worth fiddling it and seeing.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to have fixed my issue.  Strange because I have vncunused = 1 on every other xen guest I have, but never understood what it did that was just what a sample I was working off of over a year ago had. 

My install appears to be working!  

Thanks!